# Dominated Convergence Theorem for function with jump

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

I'm wondering about the following.

First of all $f$ does not need to be continuous in order to be integrable, or?
So suppose my function $f$ is not continuous but integrable. Further $f_n$ is a sequence of functions approximating $f$ and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$$ including the discontinuity (e.g. a jump).

Then still $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_n = \int_a^b f$$ holds?

EDIT: Let's now suppose $f'(x)$ is discontinuous, then why is $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{1} f(tx)x \, {\rm d}t = \int_0^x f(t) \, {\rm d}t$$
not an antiderivative?

I'm asking, because in the context of holomorphic functions it is (apparently) required that the integrand of $$F'(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \left\{f(tx)  + f'(tx)tx\right\} {\rm d}t = \int_0^1 {\rm d}t \, \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \, tf(tx)$$ needs to be continuous.

Comment: Yes: continuity is not necessary here.

Comment: in what manner are they approximating $f$? Pointwise? Uniform? What kind of integrals are these? Why do you reference dominated convergence in the title but nowhere in your post?

Comment: It's neithr necessary nor relevant.

Comment: @qbert: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem is what I'm doing (interchanging limits) so I should mention it somewhere?

Comment: @Diger I am confused about what you are asking. Is it whether the dominated convergence theorem holds if the limiting function is discontinuous? Certainly, the hypotheses just require that the $f_n$ are measurable (a far weaker condition than continuity, by the way) and that they are bounded uniformly in $n$ by an integrable function

Comment: Yes. I was not sure about this. It certainly makes sense that measurability is a much weaker condition, however I was not certain about discontinuity being relevant or not matters. Confirmation at least reassures me.
Nevertheless there is more context I might add later if I sorted things.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question. What do you mean by 'approximating $f$'?

Comment: To the question about "approximating how?".
Let's just assume the weakest: pointwise

Comment: @Diger then no, it is neither required nor expected. Do note however that the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable, making the result of the theorem actually make sense.

Comment: I posted some additional information.